# How to delete elements from a json array in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have a json column in postgres DB. Below is the json structure.

```
{
  "scope_id": "id1",
  "roles": [
    {
      "constraints": "[{\"assignmentId\": \"id2\"},{\"engagementId\": \"id3\"}]",
      "role_id": "id4"
    },
    {
      "constraints": "[{\"assignmentId\": \"id5\"},{\"engage,entId\": \"id6\"}]",
      "role_id": "id7"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to update the json value after deleting one of the elements in the `roles` array. Given input string as `[{"assignmentId": "id2"},{"engagementId": "id3"}]`, I want to delete the array element where `constraints` is equal to given input.

Update json value after deletion

```
{
  "scope_id": "id1",
  "roles": [
    {
      "constraints": "[{\"assignmentId\": \"id5\"},{\"engage,entId\": \"id6\"}]",
      "role_id": "id7"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to find the element first using below query but I am unable to get the result probably because the constraint is stored using escape notation

```
select position,constraints->'constraints' from table, jsonb_array_elements(scope->'roles')
with ordinality arr(constraints, position) where constraints->'constraints' = '[{"assignmentId": "id2"},{"engagementId": "id3"}]'
```